# Db2 select from range

Tags: php, pagination, db2, range, ibm-midrange

I am asked to fix a php function in my work. The prototype is:

```
function select($cols, $table, $cond, $order, $start, $max);
```

It queries the database with odbc_exec() and returns the number of rows with odbc_num_rows(). Function code is like this:

```
$this->query = "SELECT $cols FROM $table ";
if($cond) $this->query .= "WHERE $cond";
if($order) $this->query .= " ORDER BY ".$order;
```

This function is used in many places so i can't write it from scratch. It gets records from many tables. Until yesterday it was not using $max variable so it was reading all the records from the database. They are using iSeries Access ODBC Driver. I looked at [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaii/rzaiiodbc17.htm) for answer but couldn't found.

I want to use the $start variable, to start reading from $start and read $max rows. If $start is 100 and $max 50, i want to get the records between 100-150. I added this part yesterday:

```
if($max) $this->query .= " FETCH FIRST " . $max . " ROWS ONLY ";
```

I couldn't found anything useful for my problem. I know i can do it for one table using id or something like that. But i am looking for a general solution.

Comment: will the relative record number RRN(library.tablename) help?  that's more like the order the records were entered into the table...are you looking for the records 100 - 150 based on the sort order of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

First, you need the convert each column name in $cols to $table.columnName with php.

```
$this->query .= " ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, $convertedColumns
                       FROM $table ) AS tmp WHERE rownum > ". $start ." " ;
if($max) {
    $last = $start + $max;
    $this->query .= " AND rownum <= ". $last . " ";
}
```

And as result query looks like this:

```
SELECT $cols FROM 
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, $convertedCols ) AS tmp
WHERE rownum > $start AND rownum <= $max
```

Comment: The lack of an ORDER BY clause in your ROW_NUMBER() function call could present unpredictable results for any process that attempts to scroll through the results a page at a time. Even with an ORDER BY to produce a consistently sorted result, scrolling readers using this approach are still not protected from unexpected gaps that can be introduced by INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs being sent by other connections.

Comment: Should i change it? They didn't put the code on the server yet. If even ORDER BY may cause problems, should i accept it this way?

Comment: Good question. The answer to whether your pagination service is acceptable as-is depends on your application's tolerance for inconsistency when iterating through multiple pages of results. The underlying pattern promises a very convenient contract to programmers (ask me to select anything, even *, and you'll always get a handy page-by-page list of results without maintaining a direct cursor on the result set, or even a stateful database connection), but it's doing so by making a few trade-offs that may (and should) alarm programmers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

[SELECT DB2 LIMIT](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1663700-limit-db2.html)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is using a column name in OVER(ORDER BY COL1) . I may not get column names all the time. They can just use "*".